# The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter in the generic type or method error when type is known

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Consider the following code sample, where `Concrete` derives from `Base`:

```
class Base{}
class Concrete : Base {}

static void Foo<T>() where T : Base
{
    if (typeof(Concrete).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        var x = new Bar<T>(); // compile error on this line
    }
}

class Bar<T> where T : Concrete
{
}
```

On the line where I am having the compile error, I have already checked that the generic argument is assignable to the `Concrete` type. So in theory I believe there should be a way to create an instance of the Bar class.

**Is there any way I can remove the compile error? I cannot think of a way to cast the argument.**

---

Full text of compile error:

> Error 14  The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method
>   'Bar'. There
>   is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to
>   'Concrete'.

Comment: That compiles for me... is that the *actual* example? are there perhaps parameters in your real code?

Comment: Your code doesn't match the error message.  Surely you wrote `Bar<T>();`

Comment: Is there a reason that Foo doesn't have `where T : Concrete`?

Comment: while editing, you might also want to clarify the relationship between `Base` and `Concrete`

Comment: @ZaidMasud now the error is "Bar<T>()' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'" - you need to meet us half way here... can you please get it into a shape that shows the error you're asking us about, so that we can answer your *actual* question?

Comment: @ZaidMasud thanks; with that edit: there is no regular way to do that. You can hack it with reflection (`MakeGenericMethod` etc), but that is not a *good* answer. If you can remove the constraint from `Bar<T>` and do some casting (via `object`) inside `Bar<T>`, *that* might work.

Comment: @Servy I have simplified the code sample for posting, in reality Foo does other stuff where it relies on T : Base... so yes, there is a reason.

Comment: @ZaidMasud You can restrict it to *both*, that's not hard at all.  `where T : Base, Concrete`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler has no way to know that T, which is currently constraint to Base is actually Concrete, and that even if you test it before.

So:

```
Type type = typeof(Bar<>);
Type generic = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
var x = Activator.CreateInstance(generic);
```

Don't let it the chance to do it.